# Сложность наведения на окошко в очереди проверок

Tags: дефект, предложение, очередь-проверок

[В очереди проверок](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/close) есть зеленый прогрессбар, показывающий процесс получения знака. При наведение на него разворачивается окошко с прогрессом получения знаков.

[image: Прогресс в получении знаков]

На это окошко можно навестись, чтобы узнать, за что дают знак, но сделать это под силу далеко не каждому. Между окошком и прогрессбаром есть пространство, поэтому, при попытке навестись на окошко с прогрессбаром, оно просто пропадает.

[image: Попробуй успеть]

Навестись можно только если заранее за менее чем одну секунду переместить курсор под окошко, которое ещё не появилось. Хотелось бы, чтобы было удобнее. Предлагаю облегчить этот процесс.

Comment: Это под силу только самому быстрому курсору на Диком Западе.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Этой выпадашки больше нет и прогресс отображается на вкладке [статистики](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/close/stats):

> [image: статистика проверок]